# Apache zookeeper client times out

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We continuously get EndOfStreamException in zookeeper logs,

```
[2017-04-06 19:15:24,350] WARN EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15b43c712fc03a5, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

And in the client's (consumer) logs, we get session time out,

```
main-SendThread(localhost:2181) INFO  2017-04-06 21:30:27,823: org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x15b43c712fc03a5, negotiated timeout = 6000
```

Is it normal behavior ?

We are actually amid investigation for the issue and the consumers are unable to read messages from queue. And producers are unable to put in. Thus, the whole process in jammed.

What do you suggest?

Comment: check IO operations on disk (don't remember exact logs in zookeeper, but we have similar issue and it was connected with other processed that were havily used disk and cause slow operation in zookeeper)

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were running into zookeeper disconnects which were right above the 6000ms default timeout, due to flaky distributed network.  Since at that point the node takes itself out of the cluster, it was causing fairly high impact on the production cluster.  So, we simply increased the timeout to 15 seconds, and did not see the problem again.